# Jquery validation plugin not displaying messages when used with <from:form> tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, jsp, jquery-validate

**Situation :** i have the following form in a jSP page that uses jquery validation plugin from https://jqueryvalidation.org/
:

```
<form id = "form1" class="form-inline" method = "post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <fieldset>
        <legend id="searchHeader"><spring:message code="add.details.header"/></legend>  
        </fieldset>

        <div class="inputDiv" >
            <div class="formRow">
                <div class="LabelDiv"><label class="inputLabel">Name<span class="asterix">*</span>: </label></div>
                  <div class="inputElement">                    
                      <input    name="proName" id="proName"  class="required">                      
                   </div>
            </div>          
        </div>      

   <input type="button" id = "forwardButton" value="Next"/>
```

and the script to validate form is as follows :

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $("#form1").validate({
         rules: {
             proName: "required"            
        },
        messages: {
            proName: "This field is empty"

        }
    });
});

$("#forwardButton").click(function() {
        $("#form1").attr("action", "/target");
        if($("#form1").valid()){
            $("#form1").submit();
        }
});
```

**Problem :** The above form carries validation and displays error messages .

But when i try to use `<form:from>` instead of `<form>` tag the validation occurs , i even see a red border in my input field

but the custom error messages are not displayed , following is my current form :

```
<form:from id = "form1" class="form-inline" method = "post" enctype="multipart/form-data" modelAttribute="model"> 

        <fieldset>
        <legend id="searchHeader"><spring:message code="add.details.header"/></legend>  
        </fieldset>

        <div class="inputDiv" >
            <div class="formRow">
                <div class="LabelDiv"><label class="inputLabel">Name<span class="asterix">*</span>: </label></div>
                  <div class="inputElement">                    
                      <form:input name="proName" id="proName" path="dto.name" class="required"></form:input>                        
                   </div>
            </div>          
        </div>      

   <form:input type="button" id = "forwardButton" value="Next"></form:input>
```

I can't seem to understand why the messages are not bieng displayed , is Jquery validation plugin incompatible with `<form:form>` tag

Comment: Jquery only cares about the generated html. Why the form action is added on click and not before ? Are you sure that `$("#form1").valid()` is calling the `validate()` function you wrote just before ?

Comment: Looking at the documentation, It seems that `valid()` checks wether the form has been, or not, validated. BUT, the validation itself must be done with `validate()`. You should try this `$("#forwardButton").click(function() { $("#form1").validate({ ... }); if($("#form1").valid()){ ...`

Comment: tried that didnt work , is jquery validation plugin incompatible with <form:form> tag ?

Comment: I don't think so. Isn't the `<form:form>` just a server side syntax that will be  rendered to a simple html `<form>` ?? Also, there might be a typo in your code sample, `<form:from` Check that.

Comment: already checked , not typo , my original code is correct but as soon i change form to form:form my error messages dont display

Comment: can you post the generated html only ? not your source code.

Answer (score 0):

Please replace your form tag, there is a typo `<form:from` to `<form:form`

```
<form:from id = "form1" class="form-inline" method = "post" enctype="multipart/form-data" modelAttribute="model">
```

to

```
<form:form id = "form1" class="form-inline" method = "post" enctype="multipart/form-data" modelAttribute="model">
```

Working fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/3sncybnw/

Comment: its a typo my original code is correct , i am pretty sure the plugin is incompatible with <form:form> tag

Comment: i have used <form:form> tag in my project and it works just fine. Could you post the rendered html rather than the jsp code ?